# Passing model from a post method to a new get method in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an application.

I am stuck at a point from where i want to pass a model from a Post method to a Get method.

```
// Code in get method
FoundAccounts fa=new FoundAccounts();
fa.register = model;

return RedirectToAction("FoundAccounts", fa);

//Post Method
public ActionResult FoundAccounts(FoundAccounts fa)
{
//Use that values here
}
```

Can i do it like this?
I am unable to find a way.

Please help me with the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can i do it like this?

No, you can't. You can only pass simple, scalar properties to the route values of a `RedirectToAction` call. It doesn't make sense to pass complex objects, because when you perform a redirect, only the simple properties will be included in the GET request as query string parameters.

So you have different possibilities:

1. Persist the entity in your backend and then pass only the id to the GET action (this is the solution I recommend):

   ```
   int id = repository.Save(fa);
   return RedirectToAction("FoundAccounts", new { id = id });
   ```

   and then your GET action will take the id as action parameter and use this `id` to retrieve the entity from wherever you persisted it initially:

   ```
   public ActionResult FoundAccounts(int id)
   {
       FoundAccounts model = repository.Get(id);
       ...
   }
   ```
2. Pass all properties and leave the model binder dehydrate the entity in the GET action:

   ```
   return RedirectToAction("FoundAccounts", new 
   {
       prop1 = fa.prop1,
       prop2 = fa.prop2,
       ...
   });
   ```

   Obviously here if you have some complex properties you will need to pass them as well. Remember that the properties you include will be the properties you will be able to retrieve in your GET action. Everything else will be lost:

   ```
   return RedirectToAction("FoundAccounts", new RouteValueDictionary
   {
       { "prop1.SubComplexProp1", fa.prop1.SubComplexProp1 },
       { "prop1.SubComplexProp2", fa.prop1.SubComplexProp2 },
       { "prop2", fa.prop2 },
   });
   ```

   The drawback of this solution is that if you have lots of properties this could quickly become cumbersome. And you could even hit on a roadblock because there's a limitation to the size of a GET request. This limitation will vary between browsers, but I wouldn't pass anything more than 2048 characters in a GET request.
3. Use Session or TempData (not recommended as it introduces state into your application);

   ```
   TempData["fa"] = fa;
   return RedirectToAction("FoundAccounts");
   ```

   and then inside the GET action retrieve the model from the Session or TempData:

   ```
   public ActionResult FoundAccounts()
   {
       FoundAccounts model = TempData["fa"] as FoundAccounts;
       ...
   }
   ```

   The difference between Session and TempData is that TempData will survive only for a single redirect and will then be automatically evicted by the framework. Under the covers it uses Session, it's just that it is automatically cleared once you read the value in the GET action. The problem with this of course is that if the user hits <kbd>F5</kbd> to refresh the page in his browser, you will no longer find the value in TempData because it was evicted. Even worse if the user decides to bookmark the GET action, he will have the same problem if later he decides to come back and navigate to this bookmark. So people tend to use Sessions for those kind of things. Sessions of course do not solve the problem with bookmarks (because the user could have closed his browser in-between and the Session will be lost). Also Sessions introduce other problems in web farm scenarios. For example if the session is stored in-memory (which is the default), this means that you could store the value on one node of the farm but when you perform the redirect you could hit another node of the farm and then this node no longer has any knowledge of the session. So people start to use an out-of-process sessions - either stored in a State Service machine or SQL service. But what's the point? I mean take a look at my first and recommended solution. It's exactly what you will end up a fortiori if you want to have scalable solution working in a web farm environments.

Comment: Ok, I am going with the 3rd method but with this i have a problem.
How can i get the value of the model contents in the post method?

Comment: What values? Your POST action already takes the model as action argument. The default model binder will then bind the submitted values from the form to the model, assuming you have respected the naming conventions.